# Comparing pandas.Series for equality when they are in different orders

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas automatically aligns data indices of Series objects before applying the binary operators such as addition and subtraction, but this is not done when checking for equality. Why is this, and how do I overcome it?

Consider the following example:

```
In [15]: x = pd.Series(index=["A", "B", "C"], data=[1,2,3])

In [16]: y = pd.Series(index=["C", "B", "A"], data=[3,2,1])

In [17]: x
Out[17]:
A    1
B    2
C    3
dtype: int64

In [18]: y
Out[18]:
C    3
B    2
A    1
dtype: int64

In [19]: x==y
Out[19]:
A    False
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool

In [20]: x-y
Out[20]:
A    0
B    0
C    0
dtype: int64
```

I am using pandas 0.12.0.

Comment: This also happens in `0.13.1` by the way, interesting question.

Answer (score 5):

You can overcome it with:

```
In [5]: x == y.reindex(x.index)
Out[5]: 
A    True
B    True
C    True
dtype: bool
```

or

```
In [6]: x.sort_index() == y.sort_index()
Out[6]: 
A    True
B    True
C    True
dtype: bool
```

The 'why' is explained here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1134#issuecomment-5347816

**Update**: there is an issue that dicusses this (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1134) and a PR to fix this (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6860)